# LDAP Users Home Directories

Tags: linux, ldap, pam

I'm trying to setup linux login via an LDAP server.

I have everything working except setting the user's home directory.  There is no parameter in the LDAP database that I can map to the homeDirectory attribute and I don't have the power to change the databse.

Is there any way I can configure it to use something like /home/$UID, where $UID is the username they're using to login/that's coming from the LDAP attribute uid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Put

```
map passwd homeDirectory "/home/$uid"
```

to `/etc/nslcd.conf` (on Debian systems, on other systems it might be `/etc/(ldap)/ldap.conf`)

Answer (score 2):

Being Linux, you can try using **PAM**:

In `/etc/pam.d/common-session` put:

```
session required      pam_mkhomedir.so   skel=/etc/skel umask=0002
```

And fill in `/etc/skel` the home template that you want for users.

At first login, the home will be created.

You will have to deal with user deletion... their homes will remain on servers.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use something like [nsscache](http://code.google.com/p/nsscache/) and then have a script that runs on the cached passwd database and modifies the user home directory attributes.

Comment: Thanks - I'm going to do that for now, but it feels a little hackish.